# LWC Quick action on WOLI (Work Order Line Item) not showing up in Dynamic record page

Tags: lightning-web-components, quickaction, lightning-quickaction

I already checked related posts on this topic and I feel I have already checked them

So I have LWC Quick action created -

```
<isExposed>true</isExposed>
<targets>
    <target>lightning__RecordAction</target>
    <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
</targets>
<targetConfigs>
    <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordAction">
        <actionType>ScreenAction</actionType>
    </targetConfig>
</targetConfigs>
```

THe apex class used has been given access to profiles.

The quick action has been added to Page layout under "Mobile and Lightning Actions"

However, I do not see the option to add this LWC quick action from a dynamic page layout

Any idea or suggestions that I can try?

Thanks

Comment: Please do not use screenshots for code or XML snippets; that prevents suggested updates from being easily created and means visually impaired users cannot help answer your question so easily.

Comment: Thank you. I updated it

Comment: What is WOLI?  Please [edit] your post to clarify.

Comment: @DavidCheng Work Order Line Item (Service Cloud/Field Service). Agreed about the use of acronyms.

Comment: updated the post

Comment: @SEuser did you ever figure this out? Struggling with the same thing, and very little documentation on it.

Answer (score 0):

Took me a bit to figure this out, but you have to enable this functionality via a permission set first. It only works for Field Service orgs on the Field Service Mobile app.

To get LWC Quick Actions working on Field Service Mobile I had to:

1. Create an LWC quick action on the Work Order object
2. Add the quick action to the page layout
3. Lastly, setup a permission set an add the `Access Lightning Web Components in Field Service Mobile` permission. For License, select `Field Service Mobile`.
4. Log out, close the app, and log back in. Open a work order, and open the action menu. The action should now appear.

Here's the related documentation with more details if needed:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_offline.meta/mobile_offline/quickstart_lwc_action_org_setup.htm?_ga=2.225303066.1870384563.1697955162-346532248.1669145955